# Как в 1С с помощью внешней обработки поставить/убрать галочку?

Tags: 1с

Для примера в разделе инвентаризация ОС есть такая форма, где есть галочки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как в 1С с помощью внешней обработки поставить/убрать галочку?

Comment: Можно через групповом изменение

Answer (score 0):

Вначале нужно открыть базу в конфигураторе; В разделе документы найти ИнвентаризацияОС; Затем выяснить название Табличной части, и название реквизита;

См примеры: https://helpme1s.ru/dokumenty-v-yazyke-1s-8-v-primerax

В обработке по нажатию кнопки прописать код типа:

```
// найдём нужный документ 
Запрос = Новый Запрос;
Запрос.Текст = 
    "ВЫБРАТЬ
    |   Ссылка
    |ИЗ
    |   Документ.ИнвентаризацияОС
    |ГДЕ
    |   Номер = &Номер
    |УПОРЯДОЧИТЬ ПО
    |   Дата ВОЗР";

Запрос.УстановитьПараметр(
    "Номер",
    "КП00-000001"
);

РезультатЗапроса = Запрос.Выполнить();

ВыборкаДокументов = РезультатЗапроса.Выбрать();

Пока ВыборкаДокументов.Следующий() Цикл        
    Док = ВыборкаДокументов.Ссылка.ПолучитьОбъект();
    Для каждого Стр из Док.ТабличнаяЧасть Цикл
        Стр.ИмяРеквизита = Истина;
    КонецЦикла;
    Док.Записать(РежимЗаписиДокумента.Запись);
    // .Записать(РежимЗаписиДокумента.Проведение);
КонецЦикла;
```